# SELECT COUNT() vs mysql_num_rows();

Tags: php, mysql, select, optimization, large-data

I have a large table (60+) millions of records.

I'm using PHP script to navigate through this table.

PHP script (with pagination) loads very fast because:

The table engine is InnoDB thus `SELECT COUNT()` is very slow and `mysql_num_rows()` is not an option, so i keep the total row count (the number that i use to generate pagination) in a separate table (i update this record `total_rows=total_rows-1` and `total_rows=total_rows1+1` during `DELETE` and `INSERT`).

But the question is what to do with the pagination for search results?

Right now I'm doing this with 2 steps:

1.

```
$condition = " fname='rinchik' ";
$result = "SELECT * FROM my_large_table WHERE" . $condition;
```

Here i got all search results from DataBase.

2.
Now i need to count these results to create pagination.
I'm doing this:

```
$condition; <- we already have this from the step 1
$result_count = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM my_large_table WHERE" . $condition;
```

And it's kinda slow.

Would it be better if i will do it this way (with just one step)?:

```
$condition = " fname='rinchik' ";
$result = "SELECT * FROM my_large_table WHERE" . $condition;
$result_count = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the less calls you make to the database the faster your code will be.

Comment: Rather than `COUNT(id)` (which requires MySQL to inspect whether the `id` of each record is `NULL` and therefore should be excluded from the count), you should use `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @eggyal ID is never null. I'm not sure about the inspection process but i think that its only the case if you will set "ALLOW NULL" for the column.

Comment: @rinchik: It's the semantics of `COUNT(expr, ...)` vs `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: @AntonSoradoi That's a general rule I'm aware of. There are always some exceptions.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `COUNT`, internally the server will process the request differently.

When doing `COUNT`, the server will only allocate memory to store the result of the count.

When using `mysql_num_rows`, the server will process the entire result set, allocate memory for all those results, and put the server in fetching mode, which involves a lot of different details, such as locking.

Think of it like the following pseudo scenarios:

**`SELECT COUNT(*)`**

> Hey Bob, how many people are in the class room?

**`mysql_num_rows`**

> Hey Bob, send all the people from the classroom over to me, ... I'll count them to get the number of people myself

In summary, when using `mysql_num_rows` you are transferring all records to the client, and the client will have to calculate the count itself.

Comment: What if ill get a 1m rows in a results? Memory is not an issue. The question is what would be faster?

Comment: Now about my question: Bob already gave me the list of all people. Should i ask Bob how many people in the class room? Or should i use the list that he gave me and count myself?

Comment: If you already have the data, then doing a num_rows would be the faster thing to do (as you're not making another query), but you said you're using pagination, so would the num_rows would be a limit of the paged result set, not the total?

Comment: I got some results from DB. I have 10 results per page. So i need to count the total amount of pages (count(results)/10) and generate navigation links. Since i already have data from DB i'm asking if i should use (count($query_again)/10) of (mysql_num_rows(results)/10)

Comment: The way I would do it is have two queries.  First query to get the total count, then the 2nd to get the paginated data using `LIMIT x OFFSET y`.

Answer (score 3):

Use COUNT(id). It only returns the count, With `mysql_num_rows($result);` php fetch ALL the data from the mysql and count the number of found results.

And finally, don't use mysql_* functions.

> Suggested alternatives
>
> Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL
>   extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and
>   related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function
>   include:
>
> mysqli_stmt_num_rows() PDOStatement::rowCount()

Comment: well then apply this to mysqli_num_rows

Answer (score 2):

Tested in `inoDB` engine and mysql 5.5.

The `id` has index and I think this is very fast

```
$q = "SELECT count(`id`) FROM table where 1";
$rows = mysql_query($q);
$count = mysql_fetch_array($rows);
echo $count[0];
```

if you want more, you have to use one index just on `id` or what ever you want to select.

Caching is another solution and you can select from 1 set of records in **few milliseconds**!