# Validating email address in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating some client side validation for my email field. Checking if the email already exists in the database. However the result always says that the email address is available whether it already exists or not.

here's my JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#email_address").blur(function() {
        var email = $("#email_address").val();
        $("#emailError").html('<img alt="" src="img/loading.gif"/>');
            $.post("check_username_new.php", {email:email},
            function(result) {
                if (result > 0) {
                    $("#emailError").html("Not Available");
                    console.log(result);
                }
                else {
                    $("#emailError").html("Available");
                    console.log(result);
                    }
                });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
  require('includes/application_top.php');

$email = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST["email_address"]));
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM customers WHERE customers_email_address = '" . $email . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo 1;
}
else {
    echo 0;
}

?>
```

As far as I can tell, my jQuery is working, and seems to be an issue with the php. I am not getting any errors to work from either, so naturally I am a bit stuck.

Comment: I'm sure there's more to it than this, but I would update the PHP script to use $_GET['email_address'] and test it yourself in a browser. Do you get a blank screen still?

Answer (score 2):

You are using `COUNT` which will return `0` if not data found and the number of records found. In both of the cases there will be a `row` in the resource. So `mysql_num_rows` will always be `1`.

You should do -

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); // You can use any fetch method
if($data['count(*)'] > 0) {
    echo 1;
}
else {
    echo 0;
}
```

> **mysql** is deprecated. Prefer using **PDO** or **mysqli**

Comment: I tried this method, and yes before I noticed that my query was always returning 1. Now this returns as 0. However I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: My bad. Check the updated answer. use `assoc` instead of `object`.

Comment: The result is now the opposite, every value entered now returns as not available, could this be an issue with my php not reading the database properly?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you should do

```
count(*)
```

or

```
mysql_num_rows()
```

not both.

count is probably better, see [SELECT COUNT() vs mysql_num_rows();](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864557/select-count-vs-mysql-num-rows)