# Count(id) mysql - show 0 if no results?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to count(id) if an user has new chat messages.

My problem is if there is no message it doesn't give me 0 as a result.
What is wrong?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(id) FROM chat WHERE `to`=? and recd='0' group by `from`");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($chatcont);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
```

php:

```
echo "($chatcont)";
```

if no message I have:

```
()
```

I want to show 0 inside this.

Comment: I believe that `NULL` output is coming instead of `0` in the count because of the `GROUP BY` command. When there are `0 rows` in the output, the GROUP BY command cannot GROUP anything, thus producing a NULL structure.

Comment: oh, you are right! group by is the problem here... should I use num rows instead? because I need to count messages by senders, not by the real number of messages...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of questions that, being wrongly put, make people writing wrong answers all around.

Using SQL *properly*, `count()` will *always* return a number.

It's SQL which is wrong. While accepted answer is essentially wrong and should never be used, as it [has been answered here thousands times already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864557/select-count-vs-mysql-num-rows), all in vain.

```
SELECT count(id) FROM chat WHERE `to`=? and recd='0'
```

is the right answer to get **the number of unread messages.**

To get the number of senders is **another question**. That can could have been answered with SQL as well. If were *ever asked*.

```
SELECT count(distinct `from`) FROM chat WHERE `to`=? and recd='0'
```

Comment: @RickJoe this one looks like the only correct answer to me. Why you need to use group by?

Answer (score 2):

Use `$stmt->num_rows` to return the number of rows in your result.
If that is 0 then `echo 0` else `echo $chatcont`

Comment: thank you! the problem in count is group by as Anshuman Chatterjee said! I think the solution is num_rows indeed... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yet you don't need to use bind_result in PDO statements. Please, avoid unnecessary actions.
Just get your data and use it anywhere.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT count(id) as count FROM chat WHERE `to`=? and recd='0' group by `from`");
$stmt->execute(array($user));
$chatcont = $stmt->fetch();

echo $chatcont['count'];
```

Here, you will get either count or 0

Comment: there is no PDO around