# Mysql COUNT(*) and myql_num_rows in php: Which is faster?

Tags: php, mysql

I wan to know the difference between getting row count via `select COUNT(*) from table` fetching data AND `mysqli_num_rows($ofquery)`(in php)?

I tried in both ways and works well. But method is faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT`, internally the server will process the request differently.

When doing `COUNT`, the server will only allocate memory to store the result of the count.

When using `mysqli_num_rows`, the server will process the entire result set, allocate memory for all those results, and put the server in fetching mode, which involves a lot of different details, such as locking.

Think of it like the following pseudo scenario:

1) Hey , how many people are in the class room? (count)

2) Hey , get me a list of all the people in the classroom, ... I'll calculate the number of people myself (mysqli_num_rows)

`count` is the best than `mysqli_num_rows`

[Reference from here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12864557/select-count-vs-mysql-num-rows)

Comment: Don't copy-paste identical answers (espacially the ones using `mysql_*` instead of `mysqli_*`, even if the difference is slim in this particular case). In this case, just close the question as duplicate.